# rubymine - Could not find gem "jquery-rails"

Tags: ruby, rubymine

I have installed rubymine and Ruby193 (with rubyinstaller).
I now create a rails aplication with "preconfigured for selected database" - "mySqL " checkbox selected
When I click the execute it prints  the following error :

D:/Programs/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.1.3/lib/bundler/resolver.rb:287:in `resolve': Could not find gem 'jquery-rails (>= 0) x86-mingw32' in the gems available on this machine. (Bundler::GemNotFound)

ideas?

Comment: `gem install jquery-rails` from the command line terminal

Comment: Thanks CrazyCoder. You have been helping me a lot in this forum lately.  can you recommend a good tutorial to rubymine . because in jet brains site this solution , for instance, is not mentioned

Comment: Get familiar with RubyGems, you'll be using it a lot. jQuery-Rails has nothing to do with your RubyMine installation; it's a pretty basic dependency problem with your Gemfile ([Bundler](http://gembundler.com/rationale.html) handles that). Running `bundle install` may help.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Install this gem separately:

`gem install jquery-rails`

or via [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/rationale.html)

`bundle install` (in the project directory where your Gemfile is located)

Comment: Is there a jetbrains rubymine way to do it ?
 or a tutotrial for JetMine that helps noobs?
 thanks.

Comment: RubyMine should detect missing gems automatically by analyzing your Gemfile and Ruby SDK paths and suggest to install them via balloon notification. You can also run `bundle install` directly from RubyMine. Documentation is available at http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/getting-help.html.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the latest version of jquery-rail to install in ubuntu via terminal:

**gem install jquery-rails -v 4.0.4**

Answer (score 0):

On Windows (at least from what I was just doing) rubymine fails to install gems with bundle install that are very easily installed from the command prompt using the gem install command as shown above.

This will install the gem which will allow you to rerun the rubymine bundler to create your bundle.

*I wanted to put this on the answer above me as a comment but I can't add it for some reason.

There must be some option to let the bundle command in rubymine to download new gems. Is it --system?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem recently and found a simple way to bypass it. 
CD into the project folder and check the gemfile to make sure the gems are present. 
Run bundle install in the project folder. This should install the missing gems into the project folder. Everything worked fine for me after that.