# Rails server is not starting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

i have succesfully installed rails 3.2.8, ruby 1.9.3, gems are also updated.
when rails server command is entered in myapp folder following error is displayed

←[31mCould not find gem 'jquery-rails (>= 0) x86-mingw32' in the gems available
on this machine.←[0m
←[33mRun `bundle install` to install missing gems.←[0m

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123761/rubymine-could-not-find-gem-jquery-rails

Comment: Did you do what it says you to do? (Run `bundle install` to install missing gems)

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the corresponding gems by using
`gem install jquery-rails`
or run the `bundle install` command in console before you start the rails server?